# Oracle Apex IG Excel download error unreadable content

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am getting an error with excel file downloaded via ections in test environment for IG.

This is the default download functionality.

It says excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing content.
If i save and close file and reopen, the error doesn't show.

Is this related to Apex or excel related?